# Nulling objects passed as parameters, garbage collection?

Tags: actionscript, garbage-collection

If I create a new object:

```
var objA:Object = new Object;
```

and then I pass it into an instance of a class:

```
var objB:Class = new B(objA);
```

and this is my destroy function inside of class B:

```
public function destroy():void
{
  __objA = null // __objA being just objA
}
```

Does that destroy objA or does that just destroy a reference to the object inside of the instance of class B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe objA will be destroyed.  The reference itself ( __objA ) will be destroyed, but objA will continue to live on forever since the variable __objA merely points to objA.

Answer (score 0):

objA and __objA are just references to an object created by "new Object".  That object will not be destroyed as long as there is at least one reference to it still in existence.

For example, if objA is a local variable to a method, then as soon as the method finishes executing the objA reference no longer exists.  Except of course if the method has any continuations (anonymous event listeners).  If that's the case, objA will stay around until the listener is removed.